# Schwarz Reflection Principle vs. Analytic Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

Analytic continuations are unique on simply connected domains:
$$F,F':\Omega\to\mathbb{C}:\quad F\restriction=F'\restriction\implies F=F'$$

Schwarz reflection principle offers analytic continuations from half spaces:
$$f:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad F\restriction=f\quad(F(\overline{Z}):=\overline{f(z)})$$

But there are analytic functions not respecting this:
$$f(z):=iz:\quad f(\overline{z})\neq\overline{f(z)}$$

So the uniqueness must be false, is it, really??

Comment: Your example does not satisfy $f(x)$ is real for $x$ on the real axis.

Comment: Aahaaah ok, so the Schwarz reflection principle gives really **the only** possible continuation?

Comment: See the wikipedia article.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle

Comment: The Schwarz reflection principle asserts that one may extend an analytic function defined on the upper half space which has real values on the real axis to the whole complex plane.  The extension asserted is the only possible analytic extension, and moreover, it IS an analytic extension.  I have turned this into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analytic continuation is unique on a connected set.  Your example does not satisfy $f(x)$ is real for $x$ on the real axis, which is necessary to apply the Schwarz reflection principle.

Comment: Connected suffices since that identity theorem?

Comment: Yes, if two analytic functions on an open connected set agree on some open set they agree everywhere.